# call to super in a constructor implicitly or explicitly if commented or not. has same effect

Tags: java, super

```java
class Person { 
    Person() { 
        System.out.println("This is person class"); 
    } 
} 

class Student extends Person {
    Student() {
        super();
        System.out.println("This is student class");
    }
}
    
class Test { 
    Student s = new Student();
}
```

The output is

> This is person class
> This is student class

But if I comment super() call in child class constructor, output is coming same, is it like, giving super() in child class is explicit call to a constructor?

Comment: Exactly - if there is a default super constructor, i.e. one with an empty parameter list, it is implicitly called unless you specify a different one.

Comment: so if I have a parameterized constructor, then I will have to give explicit call in child class constructor to super() with respective parameters? @Hulk

Comment: Yes, that is correct.